# Compare two txt files and make changes so they are indentical

Tags: batch-file

I have two files, one is old where "some" data from this file needs to be overwritten into the second file.  The files are actually .reg files.  In these files, there are about 30 keys that are defined but only about 10 keys need to be updated. An example of the two files are shown below.

file(old).reg

---

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOMETHING\PERM\PhoneNumber]
@="1234567"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOMETHING\PERM\ClientCode]
@="B01"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT....]
"Account Name"="blah,blah,blah.com"
"ServerName"="PCCCCP"

Etc.
Etc.

file(new).reg

---

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOMETHING\PERM\PhoneNumber]
@="XXXXXXX"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOMETHING\PERM\ClientCode]
@="XXX"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT....]
"Account Name"="blah,blah,blah.com"
"ServerName"="XXXXXX"

Etc.
Etc.

---

Can anyone assist?  Is this easier with batch or with vbscript?  I am learning both at this time and perhaps this request is a bit over my head.  All I'm looking for is code snippets.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: why not use `xcopy` to overwrite?

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%F IN (`type old.reg` ^| FIND /V /I "string you wish to omit"`) DO (ECHO %%F>>new.reg)
```

For each additional string, add another ^| FIND /V /I "string you wish to omit" as such:

```
(`type old.reg` ^| FIND /V /I "string you wish to omit" ^| FIND /V /I "string you wish to omit" ^| FIND /V /I "string you wish to omit"`)
```

Then just echo your new strings as an output to that file.  I haven't messed with .reg files before, so I'm not sure if they need to be in a specific order?  If so you're screwed for batch script at least =P

Comment: I thought about using FC (file compare) but the output is a little too unorganized and I don't really see a way to output it to make it useful without having to waste a lot of time figuring it out.